# Where to find actual legal code for Uniform Gifts to Minors Act (UGMA)?

Tags: united-states, law, texas, utma-ugma

Does anyone know where I can find the actual legal code for [UGMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Gifts_to_Minors_Act) in Texas and the US?  I can only find a bunch of sites that quote bits and pieces of the code.  I couldn't find anything in the [Texas Legal Code](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Search.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I believe the statute you are looking for is in the Texas Property Code — Section 141, otherwise known as [Texas Uniform Transfers to Minors Act](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:L0sgPt5_IBoJ:www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/PR/word/PR.141.doc+Texas+Property+Code+-+Section+141.010&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) (**UTMA**) (available in [.doc file format](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/PR/word/PR.141.doc) on the Texas website). The Wikipedia article “[Uniform Gifts to Minors Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Gifts_to_Minors_Act)” states that, in many places, UGMA has been replaced by UTMA.